# AutoMapper Dependency Injection into Profile classes

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

I added dependencies to my profile class:

```
public class MyModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MyModelMappingProfile(
        IDependency1 dependencyOne, IDependencyTwo dependencyTwo)
```

When I start the service it complains `System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'MyModelMappingProfile'.`

Found [this solution](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/how-to-inject-service-in-automapper-profile-class/), which solves the problem, but is very manual. Is there something more generic? Haven't found an answer in the docs

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/141#issuecomment-1079914176

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reference. I agree with Jimmy on several things, but not on this one

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I think you can convert this to answer

Comment: @chester89 did you find a solution?

Comment: @EgoPingvina I got rid of the dependency - in my scenario it wasn't worth it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/

X DO NOT inject dependencies into profiles

Profiles are static configuration, and injecting dependencies into them can cause unknown behavior at runtime. If you need to use a dependency, resolve it as part of your mapping operation. You can also have your extension classes (resolvers, type converters, etc.) take dependencies directly.

Comment: > resolve it as part of your mapping operation.
And how should I do this? All my profiles are inherited from the base one, which should depend on the Foo service. How to reach it?